# Conda Environment not activated in Git Bash

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I've installed Git Bash and I'm using python which was installed via Anaconda.
I've already activated the environment within the Conda prompt and when I open Git Bash and type python, I get an error (see image below) but when I add add Anaconda3/python it works like a charm (see same image).

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBdhA.png)

But I get a warning even tho I've used `activate conda base` in the conda prompt.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On command prompt do, "where python" and "where conda" and send the output to us.

Comment: I'm thankful for your comment and I apologize for not answering before. I don't have the PC with me anymore so I couldn't do when you told me to. But thanks anyway! Have a great day.